# Edit toolbar and preview aren't loading correctly for tag wikis

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, editor, markdown-preview

When I try to create or edit a tag wiki, I don't see the edit toolbar, neither do I see the preview below the post:

> [image: No preview or edit toolbar]

When I attempt to load an editing form for a post, it *briefly* shows like this, but then the toolbar and preview load properly. However, when loading an editing form for a tag wiki, it remains stuck at this state.

I see the following in my JS console:

> [image: See quote below]
>
> ```
> "showLowRepImageUploadWarning"in e.imageUploader||(e.imageUploader.showLowRepImageUploadWarning=e.showLowRepImageUploadWarning
> ```
>
> Invalid operand to '`in`': Object expected

Using Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Repro on several sites (Meta, SFF, Movies) - Windows 10, Firefox 64.0.2