# Toolbar options are not displaying in Edit Profile - About me section

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, editor

Toolbar options are not displaying in [Edit Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) page **About me** section.

Issue can be reproduced in all the Stack Exchange sites.

> [image: Toolbar]

Seeing the following error in Google Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'showLowRepImageUploadWarning' in undefined
>   at new StackExchange.MarkdownEditor (wmd.en.js?v=50f41773693e:2)

Comment: Same issue for tag wikis: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322917/edit-toolbar-and-preview-arent-loading-correctly-for-tag-wikis

Comment: Reproduced on several sites (Meta, SFF, Movies) - Windows 10, Firefox 64.0.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We added a warning shown to low rep users trying to upload an image to their question or answer. The tag wiki editor and the profile pages don't (yet?) have the inline image uploader hooked up... hence the `undefined` object in the error.

I just pushed a fix and will build it out to production shortly.