# Tag wiki and profile editors missing control toolbar

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-wiki, editor, toolbar

When I was trying to create/edit a tag wiki on iOS Chrome/Safari ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/128)), I didn't have a toolbar:

[image: blank space]

Note that the edit summary field is also (usually) missing. After you submit, it auto fills "added *X* characters in body" for both edits, with different values of *X* for both suggestions. Good luck reviewing that...

This also happens when editing my profile, like in an [older bug that was supposed to be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322938/323179).

I don't have this issue when editing posts.

This seems to be related to iOS 14.8.1 and up because iOS 14.8 doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: This often happens when the wmd.js fails to load. Is that something you can diagnose on iOS?

Comment: @rene I tried chrome://inspect/ but it didn't show anything on that page.

Comment: It did happen before https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322917/edit-toolbar-and-preview-arent-loading-correctly-for-tag-wikis but that was not on iOS/Chrome which I assume is somehow the root cause today.

Comment: Does it only happen when editing Tag Wiki's?

Comment: @rene it's also when editing my profile. Added more details.

Comment: Does not seem iOS specific - reproduced on an Android device, mobile Chrome. In desktop view on the same browser everything is a-ok, so it might actually be a styling issue.